# Recover database with laravel migrations

Tags: database, laravel

I lost my database since i moved servers.
I still have the migrations in my laravel folder. And i also have this rater.sql file in the root of my project. Is there a way i could get my database back with the migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dumped your database, your data is lost.
You can though restore the data structure with

```
php artisan migrate
```

Obviously, we do not know what `rater.sql` contains, so I suggest you look if any data can be recovered from this file.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 3):

If you are using shared hosting you cant run command, so you can open your files in an FTP file manager (I prefer PHPStorm), then you can run below command as Hedam said:

```
php artisan migrate
```

now you can export the database to your localhost and import that on your hosting.